# How to properly use parentheses in a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, hive

I have confusion regarding how to use parentheses in a SQL query.

The query below throws an error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException cannot recognize input near '(' '(' 'SELECT' in from source

Query:

```
Select 
    customer_id, order_id, city, 
From 
    ((query_1 ) as A 
    join
    (query_2 ) as B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id) C
```

But on the other hand the query below works

```
Select 
    customer_id, order_id, city, 
From 
    (query_1) as A 
join
    (query_2) as B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id
```

Update: I'm running this on Hive

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Remove the `C` from the first query and it will work

Comment: @PhilipAdler I'm running this on Hive.

Comment: `(query_1 ) as A 
    join
    (query_2 ) as B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id` is not a sub-query therefore should not be wrapped by brackets

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, by sub-query you mean something like what @verhie has written in his answer as in `select * from .... `?

Answer (score 2):

The first query throws an error because the nested query has no output fields. Fix it by adding 'select * from' or 'select [list_the_fields] from':

```
Select 
C.customer_id, C.order_id, C.city, 
From 
(select * from (query_1 ) as A 
join
(query_2 ) as B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id) C
```

But your second query would be better